# decider for a question not clear

Tags: turing-machines

This question was asked and answered but I cannot understand the solution.

1. Why is it sufficient to test all strings of |Q| + 1 length?
2. Why should special state q be found?

the original question:
[Show that the set of all TMs that move only to the right and loop for some input is decidable](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43892/show-that-the-set-of-all-tms-that-move-only-to-the-right-and-loop-for-some-input?rq=1)

L2={ M | M is a TM and there exists an input w such that in the computation of M(w) the head only moves right and M never stops}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How this language is decidable?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/127096/how-this-language-is-decidable)

Comment: No. there is no answer there. I have the solution, I can't understand it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decider for the family of Turing machines that move infinitly to the right on some input](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3180/decider-for-the-family-of-turing-machines-that-move-infinitly-to-the-right-on-so)

Answer (score 0):

The pigeonhole principle. If you go through $|Q|+1$ states, then there must be a state you have been in twice already. This means that because the input is $\sqcup$ almost all of the time, then we are stuck in a loop and the machine wont halt

Comment: I am trying to decide if there is a word w, that in the computation of M(w) the head only moves right and M never stops. How does reviewing a finite number of words in |Q|+1 help?

Comment: If you a word that reaches the special state that gets you stuck in a loop, you are done.
To find one, look at the state-transition graph of $M$ and use any standard algorithm to find if a path exists to the special state

Comment: איפה בא לידי ביטוי החלק שהמכונה זזה רק ימינה?

Comment: The machine will see only the $\sqcup$ symbol (after reading $w$). There will be no moving left or staying in place - so writing into the tape is pretty useless as it does not affect the run. Moving only to the right ensures that we will always read the same symbol - and therefore be able to know there is a definite cycle. Also it helps find the $w$ that reaches the "special" state (think why)